# How to upload image from android to remote server using c# (Asp.Net)

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

I want to upload image from Android app to remote server. I am Using Asp.Net as server side to store image. Following is code for android side and c# but i can not able to do it.

Android Code where encodedString is Base64 encode string . That i want to send it to server.

```
private class JSONParseProfilePic extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Profile.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Uploading image");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            JSONStudentParser jParser1 = new JSONStudentParser();

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("encodedData", encodedString));


            String url="http://127.0.0.1/webservice/imageUpload.aspx";
            JSONObject json = jParser1.getJSONFromUrl(url, params);

            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            try {

                String result = json.getString("result").toString();
                Toast.makeText(Profile.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                pDialog.dismiss();


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                String ms=e.getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Error"+ms, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Asp.Net Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;


public partial class webservice_imageUpload : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string vTitle = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["encodedData"]))
        {
            vTitle = Request.Form["encodedData"];
        }


        Base64ToImage(vTitle);

        //image.Save(Server.MapPath("~/webservice/img.png"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);


    }

    public System.Drawing.Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {
        // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
          imageBytes.Length);

        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: You should not use a web page (.aspx) for this, as you don't need UI elements. Instead, you should use a generic handler (.ashx). Or if you need more sophistication, look into [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: yes, but how can i get data from android app and convert it in to image to store on remote server